# How can I provide useful feedback to Mac Photos software designers?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I have been experiencing a number of issues since migrating from iPhoto to Photos, and I would like to provide useful input/feedback to the Apple software designers.

What would the best way to do that?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Ask Different. I have edited your post to make it about your specific question. I recommend you review [How do I ask a good question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to get started on how to use this site. Please keep in mind that none of us contributors here are Apple employees, so we cannot act upon your suggestions or complaints.

Comment: As for your issues with migrating from iPhoto to Photos, please feel free to open a new Question detailing what your problem is. I’m sure some of our knowledgeable members can help you with that. This site works best if we keep it down to 1 question per post, which is why I’ve trimmed your post to the essence of what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does provide a [feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/photos.html) where you can submit suggestions/complaints/ideas.

You won’t get a response, and there are no guarantees they will implement your ideas, but I’ve seen good evidence on a number of occasions that Apple does take such feedback seriously.

When voicing your concerns just remember that respectful discourse is far more likely to make an impact.